# How do I properly setup numerical integration in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I'm looking to integrate this expression:

[image: Normal Distribution function:]

However I seem to be having problems setting up the function.  As outlined in [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/quad.html) MATLAB explanation, I've defined a separate function named 'NDfx.m' which looks like this:

```
    function [ y ] = NDfx(x)
    
    y = (1/sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-.5*x^2); % Error occurs here
    
    end
```

However when I call it within my main function I get an error at the commented line above.  My main function looks like this:

```
function[P] = NormalDistro(u,o2,x)

delta = x-u;
dev = abs((delta)/o2);           % Normalizes the parameters entered into function
P_inner = quad(@NDfx,-dev,dev);  % Integrates function NDfx from -dev to dev (error here)
P_outer = 1 - P_inner;           % Calculation of outer bounds of the integral

if delta > 0
    P = P_inner + (P_outer/2);
    
elseif delta < 0
    P = P_outer/2;

elseif dev == 0
    P = .5;
    
end
end
```

The specific error that I get is:

> Error in ==> mpower
>
> Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix

Comment: Or you could switch to Mathematica, for example your answer - www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate[e^(-x^2/2)/Sqrt[2Pi],x]

Comment: Although that's great I'm writing a function for others that will be using this as well in MATLAB...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've setup everything correctly for integration.  The error is in the definition of the function itself.  When using variables for function that will be integrated, a "." (period) must precede operators like `^` and `*` when they are applied to the variable:

```
function [y] = NDfx(x)

    y = (1/sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-.5*(x.^2));

end
```

Comment: The dot is needed so that the exponentiation is done on a per-element basis, rather than trying to raise a matrix to a power (the operator `.^` is different from the operator `^`). This is necessary because the numerical integrator will pass in a vector of values to `NDfx`, and the function needs to be applied to each value individually, with the results returned in a vector of the same shape as the one passed in. This is what's known as a *vectorized* function, and it is more efficient than calling the function again for each new value at which it needs to be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Krono and user57368 are correct. They have already correctly answered your actual question. My answer is merely to answer the question you did not ask. That is, why are you using quad here at all? The point is that many people want to integrate a function of that form, and it has been done already! Use existing tools to solve your problems, as those tools will often have been written by someone who knows how to solve the problem accurately and efficiently.

In this case, the existing tool is comprised of the functions erf and erfc. They provide an accurate, efficient, vectorized solution to your problem. The only thing you will need to do is figure out how to transform those integrals to your current problem, done by a simple scaling of the input to erf and the output.

Comment: I also wanted to post a question that addresses how to setup numerical integrals within MATLAB as this has not been addressed properly before.  Now a user that's looking to setup a integral in MATLAB can easily find it here.